# How to use Sass in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, sass, visual-studio-2013

How can I use the Sass CSS preprocessor in **Visual Studio 2013**? Are there any extensions that provide support for Sass?

Comment: take a look [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/coffeescriptsassandlesssupportforvisualstudioandaspnetwiththemindscapewebworkbench.aspx)

Comment: SASS support has [been announced for VS2013 Update 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/25/announcing-new-web-features-in-visual-studio-2013-update-2-ctp2.aspx), which is in Community Tech Preview at the time of writing.

Comment: In case you are wondering, this question is being [discussed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326981/692942) on [meta].

Answer (score 86, accepted):

## Visual Studio 2013 Update 2

Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 has native syntax support for both SCSS and LESS files. You can create SCSS or LESS files and see syntax highlighting and intellisense for these file types.
**It does not however provide a method of compilation.**

Here's a **[link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/25/announcing-new-web-features-in-visual-studio-2013-update-2-ctp2.aspx)** to the blog explaining about the new features:

> We added LESS in VS2013 RTM, and we now have a SASS project item and
> editor.  SASS editor features are comparable to LESS editor, include
> colorization, variable and Mixins IntelliSense, comment/uncomment,
> quick info, formatting, syntax validation, outlining, goto definition,
> color picker, tools option setting etc.

***Please note:**
This update seems to support the newer SassyCSS syntax only. I've tried getting it to work with the older indented SASS syntax without any success.*

#### Compilation

- **[Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/)**. This is a great tool which does all the 'grunt' work
  for you. Newer versions of Web Essentials are available for Visual
  Studio 2013 Update 3, 4 and 5.
- Another free one that just handles compilation is **[CompileSASS](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2e7b72e0-f6ca-4e5e-9b30-afcc07d801f0)** this also works in VS2015.
- Alternatively you could use **[MindScape's WebWorkbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench)**, which is a
  great tool with lots of nice features. There is a free version which does just about enough to get by but there is also a paid version which is far more comprehensive (but in my opinion a little too expensive considering there is a better free alternative).

---

## Visual Studio 2015

For those of you moving to Visual Studio 2015, unfortunately there is still **no** native support for SASS and LESS compilation. And unfortunately Web Essentials will **no longer** be supporting compilation either.
The author of Web Essentials (Mads Kristensen) explains the reason for this decision [here](http://madskristensen.net/post/bundling-minification-and-client-side-compilation).

Here are a list of extensions that can handle compilation:

**WebCompiler (FREE)**

Mads Kristensen (the author of web essentials) has created a standalone compilation tool called [Web Compiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/25/announcing-new-web-features-in-visual-studio-2013-update-2-ctp2.aspx). All you have to do is install it, then right click on any of the SASS files you want to compile and select Web Compiler > Compile File. From that point on it is watched and anytime it is saved, the file will be compiled.

[Download Web Compiler](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b329021-cd7a-4a01-86fc-714c2d05bb6c)

**CompileSASS (FREE)**

Similar to Web Compiler this is a standalone extension that was created to work in both **VS2013** and **VS2015** because compilation was removed from the popular Web Essentials extension. It's lightweight and does the job very well with great error reporting. Read the author's blog about the extension [here](http://vswebessentials.com/).

[Download Compile SASS](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2e7b72e0-f6ca-4e5e-9b30-afcc07d801f0)

**Web Workbench (FREE/PAID)**

[Mindscape's Web Workbench](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2e7b72e0-f6ca-4e5e-9b30-afcc07d801f0) was my favourite extension for many years when compiling SASS but I have since moved away in favour of the free alternatives. Still, the Pro version is a powerful tool with many ways to customise the outputted files but it is also quite expensive ($39) considering there are free tools out there.

[Download Web WorkBench](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2b96d16a-c986-4501-8f97-8008f9db141a)

---

## Visual Studio Code

Same deal as above really, it has native support for SASS and LESS through syntax highlighting and Intellisense but lacks compilation.

Any of the compilers outlined above will work but if you wanted to set up compilation manually here is a brilliant guide:

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/css

Comment: Are you sure it supports SASS?  From what I can tell VS2013Update2 only supports SCSS syntax and compilation

Comment: I agree, it looks like VS 2013 update 2 might only supports SCSS (Sassy CSS). However it's worth noting for the Sass (Syntactically Awesome StyleSheets) beginners, that SCSS is a syntax (the newest) for using Sass. So Sass is supported but maybe only the newer SCSS syntaxt and not the older "Sass syntax".

Comment: I've created a test project and created a file using the .SASS extension (for the old syntax) and it doesn't recognise it, and it doesn't apply syntax highlighting. I've tried using the SASS syntax in an SCSS file, this time I get compilation errors. It doesn't look like it supports the old SASS Syntax, but it definetly supports the newer Sassy CSS.

Comment: @PWKad It doesn't appear to support compilation.You still need a third party plugin for this

Comment: The question refers to VS2013 and SASS transpiler is still available for the Web Essentials 2013 version. I believe they removed it only for the 2015 version.

Comment: I tried for an hour to get the old SASS (as opposed to the new SassyCSS syntax) to compile with no luck. One thing that helped me was this site http://www.sasstoscss.com/ where I converted the code to the newer syntax. I wish at least one the plugins would still support the old syntax.

Comment: Web Essentials would be an awesome solution if it had more than one error message for every error: "Something went wrong reaching: http://localhost.:". It won't work with my SASS project that compiles fine with Ruby and since it doesn't give a useful message, it's useless. Very disappointed.

Answer (score 53):

For anyone else looking for an answer to this, I'm posting to save you time as some of the answers are a little out of date.

Whilst working on a small web project in Visual Studio 2013, I wanted to use SASS for the first time. I did some digging and discovered VS 2013 Update 2 was released with native support for SASS (`.scss`) files.

After a bit more digging, and with no experience of using SASS, I installed [Web Essentials 2013 for Update 2](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361) that is used to compile and generate the corresponding `.css` files.

Even still, I wasn't clear on how it all tied together, but [this blog post](http://www.mattburkedev.com/using-sass-with-visual-studio-2013-essentials/) did a great job of explaining everything for a first timer.

**Snippets From Blog (Credit to @akatakritos)**

1. Visual Studio 2013 provides the ability to add SASS files (`.scss`)
2. Install [Web Essentials 2013 for Update 2](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361)
3. Add a new `.scss` file to your project, e.g. `styles.scss`
4. Update `styles.scss`, save, and it will auto generate a `styles.css` file under the `.scss` file
5. You can then bundle or link it like a regular `.css` file

### UPDATE July 2015:

In a later [Web Essentials update](http://vswebessentials.com/changelog), namely: Version 2.5 for Update 4 Nov 12. 2014, the SASS compiler has been removed.

Alternate compilers:

- [SassyStudio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/85fa99a6-e4c6-4a1c-9f00-e6a8129b6f4d)
- [Web Workbench](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2b96d16a-c986-4501-8f97-8008f9db141a)
- [Web Compiler](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b329021-cd7a-4a01-86fc-714c2d05bb6c) Only provides support for VS2015

Comment: @akatakritos just to let you know I linked your blog to this post.

Comment: how do you handle folder structures where mixins and other more componentized scss files exist, but all compile into the main scss, using the VS2013+WebEssentials support?

Comment: If you need to use multiple component files that are pulled into a main.scss file you can use SCSS partials. To create a partial, simply give the file name an underscore. Example: _buttons.scss and then in your main.scss file you would import it. Example: import "components/_buttons";

Comment: I don't understand the need to use Web Essentials in this process if there is native support in VS 2013 Update 2

Comment: @GôTô web essentials allows you to view compiled css in a second pane and also re-compiles it every time it saves. Have a read of the linked blog post. There is a chance this answer itself might be outdated now, so i'll check and update if that's the case.

Comment: Web essentials is not working for me. Sometimes it works, sometimes it seems like there are SCSS compilation errors, but it shows no messages.

Comment: Please update your answer, as WebEssentials from version 2.5 does not contain SASS compiler anymore.

Comment: Web Essentials for VS2013 supports SASS transpilation. I'm using the latest version 2.6.36. I believe the support was dropped only for the 2015 version.

Comment: @pauloya i'll look in to this later and update as required.

Comment: Using VS2015, Enterprise edition, in order for me to get this all working, I had to first download and install [https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6edc26d4-47d8-4987-82ee-7c820d79be1d] and then [https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b329021-cd7a-4a01-86fc-714c2d05bb6c]

Story: Then I had to restart VS2015, and it worked.  Originally, after downloading Web Compiler, through NuGet Package Manager, restarting VS2015, it failed to load/work or add the "compilerconfig.json" to the root of my project.  After downloading and installing Web Analyzer, it worked. Same author...

Answer (score 12):

I haven't used Chripy but there are a couple of other options you can try too.

1. My favorite extension for working with Sass in Visual Studio is Mindscape's [Web Workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench). It's well integrated, works with Visual Studio 2013 and it even supports Compass. If you use Less or CoffeeScript it will take care of those as well. I've chatted with one of the developers too and he was really responsive and friendly which is a huge plus in my book. Oh, and I hear more cool things are in the works too.
2. [SassyStudio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/85fa99a6-e4c6-4a1c-9f00-e6a8129b6f4d?SRC=VSIDE) is another possibility but it didn't seem as powerful as Web Workbench when I tried it.
3. It isn't out yet but keep an eye on [Web Essentials](http://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general/suggestions/3140436-support-for-sass-scss). At the moment it only supports LESS in terms of CSS preprocessors but Sass support has gotten a [ton of requests](http://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general/suggestions/3140436-support-for-sass-scss) and the program manager replied  that "Development underway full throttle." Hopefully soon!

The last option and the one I fall back on a lot of time is just using an external tool watch my SASS files, compile them in the background and let Visual Studio reload the CSS files as they're compiled.

Installing Ruby and SASS via command line and telling it to watch your project directory for changes works fine — but I adore [Prepros](http://alphapixels.com/prepros/) for this kind of thing.

I haven't tried them all but [Scout](http://mhs.github.io/scout-app/), [Koala](http://koala-app.com/), [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/), [Compass.app](http://compass.kkbox.com/) and [Fire.app](http://fireapp.kkbox.com/) are also similar options.

While these aren't always the right solutions for every project they give you a lot of flexibility and maturity that you won't necessarily find in Visual Studio extensions yet.

I hope that helps!

Comment: As of March 2014: This is now included in Web Essentials VS2013 Update 2 CTP 2

Comment: I really liked the Mindscape offering..  but with my new pc install underway, I may try the Web Essentials.

Comment: I installed Ruby and some auto-processing tool for my sass files when I did a little bit of Sencha Touch work a while back, but I didn't really like it.  It was decent at the time and it worked, but I like to have all my dev done in one place.  VS is such a nice environment to work in, so why use an external processing tool.  Plus if you don't need Ruby for anything else, why install it.

Comment: If you really like Visual Studio than definitely stick to integrated solutions, especially now that the options have really matured. I however am not a huge fan of VS so I only use it when I absolutely have to, I'd rather use an external solution and Sublime Text.

Answer (score 5):

To compile SCSS in Visual studio, install the [CompileSass](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2e7b72e0-f6ca-4e5e-9b30-afcc07d801f0?SRC=Home) Visual Studio Extension.

Unfortunately Web Essentials [isn't going to support compiling Sass anymore](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/releases/tag/v2.5).

I thought this was pretty sad because it was absolutely the simplest way to compile Sass from Visual Studio. I created a new Visual Studio extension that behaves the same way. You just install the extension and it will automatically compile .scss files to compressed .min.css files when you save.

Check out [CompileSass](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2e7b72e0-f6ca-4e5e-9b30-afcc07d801f0?SRC=Home).

Comment: From my understanding it will still support compiling Sass, it was just be using Visual Studio's compiler instead?

Comment: I don't think so. The author of Web Essentials (Mads Kristensen) works for Microsoft, and his recommendation is to switch to Grunt/Gulp, which use its tools to compile Sass (Ruby, right?). So the extension above provides the ability to compile Sass with no other dependencies.

Comment: This is by far the best answer to how to compile SCSS in Visual Studio.  The extension works great and is very easy to install.

Answer (score 3):

for ASP.NET there is a couple of ways to do integrate with SASS. [Chripy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/) is a common plug-in this is something you want to install in visual studio as an extension.
and thus design time compilation , you can find out more about chripy in http://chirpy.codeplex.com/ ,
as well as there is another package you can install via Nuget :

```
install-package SassAndCoffee
```

Comment: thank you, but i think the `Chripy` dosen't Supprot VS2013?

Comment: are you sure that working in VS 2013?

Comment: I'm not sure about Chripy, but second one work in VS 2013.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a blog post on this topic that I feel may help others.  Basically SCSS is supported but not the SASS extension.

http://pwkad.wordpress.com/2014/05/30/using-scss-in-visual-studio-2013-with-web-essentials-starring-compass-and-susy/

Also be careful as I have run in to a few problems compiling Compass such as in the compass/css3/images file there were breaking errors.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve the Compass problems?  Also, have you tried integrating Bourbon, and if so, how well does it work?

Answer (score 1):

My comment is probably useless as people may already have an answer, but Scout is available for windows :), I have been using in my projects since March 2013.

You could use Mixture, really powerful and creates minified version of your CSS and JS files.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Web Essentials extension - which I'd assume every web dev is running and is sort of a precursor to native VS IDE support - has SCSS compilation support, but I think it only works with VS2013 Update 2 which is in CTP still at this time.

Comment: Nope. Web Essentials does not cooperate with VS2013 Update 2 CTP (2014.04.23), and Update 2 itself has native support for SCSS files.

Comment: UPDATE: WebEssentials 2.0 RC goes with VS 2013 Update 2

Answer (score 0):

Last version of Visual Studio + last version of Web Essentials http://vswebessentials.com/download allows to use Sass and Less out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `MVC 6`, you could just use `gulp`. Original source here:
http://developer.telerik.com/featured/css-preprocessing-with-visual-studio/

Add the `NPM` dependencies in `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.8.11",
    ...
    "gulp-sass": "2.2.0",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp-sass": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Then in `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    ...
    sass = require("gulp-sass");


paths.js = paths.webroot + "js/**/*.js";
...
paths.sass = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.scss";
paths.cssOutput = paths.webroot + "css";


gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.sass)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssOutput));
});
```

Finally, in the `Task Runner Explorer`, `right-click` on your new task `sass` then `Bindings` then select `After Build`

Answer (score -3):

In Visual Studio 2013 SP 4 there is no problem adding a SCSS file and syncing on every save.  I got confused when syncing failed, I found the problem was using a variable before it was defined.   The SCSS file doesn't show any error but sync fails.

This works for sync:

```
$body-main: 45px;
body {
    padding-top: $body-main + 25px;
    padding-bottom: $body-main - 5px;
}
```

This doesn't work for sync

```
body {
    padding-top: $body-main + 25px;
    padding-bottom: $body-main - 5px;
}
$body-main: 45px;
```

In the second case there are no errors and intellisense works, but sync fails.

Comment: How does this relate to configuring Visual Studio so that it can compile Sass (which is what the question is asking)?

Comment: This is not about compiling sass in visual studio, it seems be repeat of question!