# Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 and SASS

Tags: visual-studio, sass

Anyone know how the SASS support in VS 20013 Update 2 works?

I've added all my .sass files to the project but they dont get build and there is no errors

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Use SASS in Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727102/how-to-use-sass-in-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install Web essentials for it to work

Answer (score 0):

VS 20013 Update 2 does not have support for the old .sass files only for .scss files. Try update your sass to .scss.  (I have not tried it so can not give you specific on compilation but I know they dont support .sass anyways)