# Use SASS to generate CSS for Windows Store App Project?

Tags: css, sass, windows-store-apps, compass-sass, winjs

I'm currently planning a new Windows Store App and wondered whether it would be at all possible to use SASS to help streamline some of the CSS development by utilising features such as mixins and variables etc.

I'm currently using Web Essentials to compile the SASS for web projects and wondered whether I could leverage its abilities on the app side of things.

### What I've tried:

On the off-chance that it might work... I've tried adding an SCSS file to the universal app using **Add > New Item...** but the option doesn't exist (which doesn't bode well). I tried renaming an existing CSS file's extension to `.SCSS`. However, when saving the SCSS file, VS2013 explodes in a cacophony of popups suggesting that I tell Microsoft about the problem and then restart - which isn't really the result I'm after.

Comment: What does this have to do with Windows Store App?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190888/sass-failing-to-compile-web-essentials-2013-update-4 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727102/how-to-use-sass-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: @cimmanon Hi thanks for your comments. This has everything to do with a Windows Store App because I am using HTML, CSS and JS to build the app and deploy to the windows store. Not sure if you noticed, but one of the questions you suggest is a duplicate was actually answered by myself...so its quite clearly not the same question? I'm not really sure how I can make my question easier for you to understand but here goes: I'm making an app to go in the Windows App Store. I'm making it using HTML, CSS and JS, and I want to use SASS to "write" my CSS?

Comment: These comments don't seem very constructive. I think the real question is, is SASS supported by the WinJS/Store app projects in Visual studio like they are for web projects and how?

Comment: I see what Chris is getting at. The project templates used by VS are the issue here, so this question does appear to relate directly to Windows Store Apps rather than just a simple SASS to CSS issue.

Comment: I just want to add that I attempted to recreate your issue.  I am using VS2015 with WebEssentials.  I can create and save .less/.scss files with no problem.  However, the .css files are not generated, regardless of what options and settings I use.

Comment: @JasonWilczak I haven't tried it in 2015 yet, but Web Essentials doesn't support compilation in 2015. You need to use WebCompiler. But again it's not something I have tried...yet.